# Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post to my facebook group wall but I keep on getting the above error. Can anyone please tell me what I might be doing wrong here? I have checked the Facebook documentation but I still can't seem to fix it myself. My code is as follows:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'perms' => 'offline_access, user_groups, publish_stream',
  'cookie' => true
));


$result = $facebook->api(
     '/xxxxxxxxxgroupid/feed/',
      'post',
      array('access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(), 'message' =>  'Playing around with FB Graph..')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need user_groups extended permission.

Answer (score 0):

Use Try before, that sould work fine

```
try {
        $params = array(
            'message'       =>  "Hurray! This works :)",
            'name'          =>  "This is my title",
            'caption'       =>  "My Caption",
            'description'   =>  "Some Description...",
            'link'          =>  "http://stackoverflow.com",
            'picture'       =>  "http://i.imgur.com/VUBz8.png",
        );

        $post = $facebook->api("/$user/feed","POST",$params);

        echo "Your post was successfully posted to UID: $user";

    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
       $result = $e->getResult();
    }
```